# How to add a vector as values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, histogram, arff

In line 28 I want to replace `values` with the `ch` array.  If you run the program, the values for the histogram appear at the beginning of the file.  The .arff file prints out correctly but with the `values` in the `@data` field.  Obviously, `ch` is an incompatible type.  What is the modifier for this type of structure in Java?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    int i;
    int[][][] ch = new int[4][4][4];
    FastVector attributes;
    Instances dataSet;
    double[] values;
    attributes = new FastVector();
    for (i = 0; i < 512; i++) 
    attributes.addElement(new Attribute("bin" +(i+1)))  ; 

        dataSet = new Instances("NormalizedHistogram_512bins", attributes, 3);

/*28*/  values = new double[dataSet.numAttributes()]; 
        values[0] = 3;
        values[1] =7;
        values[3] = 1;
        dataSet.add(new Instance(1.0, values));

        values = new double[dataSet.numAttributes()]; 
        values[2] = 2;
        values[3] = 8;
/*37*/  dataSet.add(new Instance(1.0, values));

    BufferedImage Image = ImageIO.read(new File("airplane_training1.jpg"));
    for(int x = 0; x < Image.getWidth(); x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < Image.getHeight(); y++) {
            int color = Image.getRGB(x, y);
            int alpha = (color & 0xff000000) >> 24;
            int red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int blue = color & 0x000000ff ;
            ch[red / 64][green / 64][blue / 64]++;
        }
    for(int k = 0; k < ch.length; k++)
        for(int j = 0; j < ch[k].length; j++)
            for(int p = 0; p < ch[k][j].length; p++)
                System.out.println( ch[k][j][p]);
    NonSparseToSparse nonSparseToSparseInstance = new NonSparseToSparse(); 
    nonSparseToSparseInstance.setInputFormat(dataSet); 
    Instances sparseImage = Filter.useFilter(dataSet, nonSparseToSparseInstance);
    System.out.println(sparseImage);

    ArffSaver arffSaverInstance = new ArffSaver(); 
    arffSaverInstance.setInstances(sparseImage); 
    arffSaverInstance.setFile(new File("ESDN.arff")); 
    arffSaverInstance.writeBatch();
 }
}
```

Comment: SOLVED.  I posted this question on IDreamInCode, did not get a response, and managed to figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Vector;

public class VectorDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   // create an empty Vector vec with an initial capacity of 4      
   Vector<Integer> vec = new Vector<Integer>(4);

   // use add() method to add elements in the vector
   vec.add(0,4);
   vec.add(1,3);
   vec.add(2,2);
   vec.add(3,1);

   // let us print all the elements available in vector
   System.out.println("Added numbers are :- "); 
   for (Integer number : vec) {         
   System.out.println("Index :"+vec.indexOf(number) +" Number: " + number);
   }

   // added new number 10 at 3rd position/index
   vec.add(3,10);

   // let us print all the elements available in vector after insertion
   System.out.println("Added numbers after insertion are :- "); 
   for (Integer number : vec) {         
   System.out.println("Index :"+vec.indexOf(number) +" Number: " + number);
   }
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffSaver;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.instance.NonSparseToSparse;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class AttTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{


    int i;
    FastVector attributes;
    Instances dataSet;
    double[] values;
    attributes = new FastVector();
    for (i = 0; i < 64; i++) 
    attributes.addElement(new Attribute("bin" +(i+1)))  ; 


        dataSet = new Instances("NormalizedHistogram_512bins", attributes, 0);

    //values = new double[dataSet.numAttributes()]; 
    //values[0] = 3;
    //values[1] =7;
    //values[3] = 1;
    //dataSet.add(new Instance(1.0, values));

    //values = new double[dataSet.numAttributes()]; 
    //values[2] = 2;
    //values[3] = 8;
    //dataSet.add(new Instance(1.0, values));

    NonSparseToSparse nonSparseToSparseInstance = new NonSparseToSparse(); 
    nonSparseToSparseInstance.setInputFormat(dataSet); 
    Instances sparseDataset = Filter.useFilter(dataSet, nonSparseToSparseInstance);

    System.out.println(sparseDataset);

    ArffSaver arffSaverInstance = new ArffSaver(); 
    arffSaverInstance.setInstances(sparseDataset); 
    arffSaverInstance.setFile(new File("ESDN.arff")); 
    arffSaverInstance.writeBatch();

    Histogram();


 }

private static void Histogram() throws IOException {
    int[][][] ch = new int[4][4][4];
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("airplane_training3.jpg"));
    for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            int color = image.getRGB(x, y);
            int alpha = (color & 0xff000000) >> 24;
            int red = (color & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            int green = (color & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            int blue = color & 0x000000ff;
            ch[red / 64][green / 64][blue / 64]++;
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < ch[i].length; j++)
            for(int p = 0; p < ch[i][j].length; p++)
                System.out.print( ch[i][j][p] + ",");
}

}
```